# Is it a unique linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that

The plane
$\{(t(1,4,1)+s(1,1,1)+(2,2,1)\}$

Is transferred  to the line
$\{t(1,2,1 )+(2,1,0)\}$

Is there only one such transformation?

Answer (score 0):

No.  The description does not specify where a vector normal to that plane gets mapped.  We don't even know if the image is $1$ or $2$ dimensional.

Comment: It cant be 1 dimension cuz ithe line doesn't  have zero in it

Answer (score 0):

No. To see this consider the translation that takes $(2,2,1)$ to $(2,1,0)$ composed with a projection of the plane onto the line. There will be infinitely many such projections including some orthogonal and some skew so the mapping cannot be unique.

Alternatively choose a vector in the plane parallel to the line, call it $p$, and construct a new line $l$ from some arbitrary point in the plane $p_0$ to an arbitrary point on the given line. As we travel in the direction of $p$ from $p_0$ in the plane continue to draw lines parallel to $l$ onto the line. Now we have a line $l_0$ in the plane that goes through $p_0$ and in the direction of $p$ all with lines that connect to the given line in a parallel fashion.

Now choose a vector orthogonal to $p$ and create a new line in the plane perpendicular to $l$ and through $p_0$. Take a new point on that orthogonal line and draw a line from it to the same point of intersection on the given line that went through $p_0$. Then repeat the construction by travelling parallel to $p$ from this new point drawing copies parallel copies of this line as you travel along it. Repeat for every point on the orthogonal line in the plane. Since the choice of where to connect $p_0$ to the line was arbitrary, there are infinitely many ways this construction can be done.

Comment: 221 goes to 210 . And then the 2 vectors  of plane must go to  121 correct?? We are left with a third one which must be the connection  from 000 to the line (otherwise  it wouldn't  be a linear space)

Comment: @Barushkish they don't go through the origin so they're not linear, they're affine which is why you do the translation first. You can think of it as moving them both to the origin if you like. There are infinitely many vectors in the plane, not two, and choosing any two linearly independent vectors as a basis and you have infinitely many ways to project them onto the line.

Comment: I didnt  get you. If you send all the plane to the line then you end up with something  that isn't  a linear space cuz the line doesn't  contain  zero. Even if you sent one of the vector to zero it's still not a linear space as you end up with a line & zero

Comment: @Barushkish Right, it's affine which is a translation then a linear transformation. You can change the origin in an affine space by $x-x_0$ for some constant vector $x_0$. In this case the translation will be $(2,2,1) - (2,1,0) = (0,1,1)$ which will place the plane on the line. Then you can move them both to the origin with $-(2,1,0)$ and project onto the line. then you move the line back by adding $(2,1,0)$. We're still only using vector operations but we include translation rather then merely linear transformations since the problem is affine.

Comment: @Barushkish I'll add a second construction to make this more transparent.

Comment: Sorry my friend  probably  my lack of knowledge.  I don't  know what it means when you say affine. Thought  a linear  transformation  must end up with a linear space. I guess if the whole transformation  was from the plane to the line that wouldn't  be valid .correct? I guess here it's ok because  the total transformation  does include more points from R3 to make it a linear  space. Now what do we must add in order  to make this img valid? We must add to it at least another vector  going from the origin to the line that would  make it a plane a valid VS . I dont see other way to make it valid

Comment: @Barushkish Affine maps are linear with translations. So for example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ all the one dimensional linear spaces are lines through the origin. An affine transformation allows the line to be anywhere in the plane. So if we have a matrix that represents a linear transformation $A$ and a fixed vector $b$ an affine transformation will be of the form $Ax +b$ with $x$ a vector valued variable. In the plane equation given $b= (2,2,1)$ and the line equation has $b = (2,1,0)$. There is nothing unusual about projecting a plane to a line. Consider $(x,y,0) \rightarrow (x,0,0)$ for example.

Comment: But who told you we are talking about affine mapping? I am studying  linear transformations.  Inside this linear transformations we got this question.  I can tell you that we had a question  about a transformation  mapping  a plane to a point. And if that point isnt (0,0,0) we said it's an invalid  transformation  cuz any other  point isnt  a linear  space even though  according  to you any point  should  be valid affine one ad it can be translated  to the origin.  So you see? We dont allow  such transformation  I guess the only  reason its valid here because  it isnt the whole  transformatio

Comment: As the transformation  includes the whole R3 space. And this is only a part of it. Mapping  a plane to  a point. That's it. But I still dont see how could we make this transformation  to be valid. I guessed  the only way to make a line valid is to transfer  another vector to be the vector going from origin to that line

Comment: @Barushkish there are no linear transformation from the plane to this line because it doesn't go through the origin. If you're allowed a linear transformation that brings both the line and plane to another linear space then I would edit the question to include this information but it would be trivially true since any proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ could be the image of such a transformation.

Comment: Again. The transformation is from R3 to R3. I repeat plane to line isnt the whole transformation.  Is only part of it. I know that the answer that it isn't  unique  is trivial.  What I dont understand  is how do we make a linear transformation  of R3 to R3 while the plane is still going to the line .  So I guess  must be the other points of the plane go somewhere  else rending the image a vector space. I am just wondering  where do they go. That's it

Comment: @Barushkish choose any line through the origin and you can project the entire space onto that as well. It will take the plane and the line to it.

Comment: Sure. But here we are talking about a line that doesnt pass through  the origin. And its supposed to be a linear space

Comment: @Barushkish but it's not a linear space, it's affine. You seem stuck on that.

Comment: I told you we aren't  studying  affine. If you were correct then a transformation  from a plane to a non zero point would be possible  but we were told it isnt possible  since the point  isnt  a linear  space